# What is the common .NET MVC workflow? Is there one portable between Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asp.net-mvc, ruby, bdd

I've been working as an apprentice/junior developer working in .NET web forms and dabbling in a ton of other stuff.

After tasting a ton of technologies I've settled on Ruby on Rails and ASP.NET MVC.

I'm struggling with workflow and I want to get into behaviour driven development.

What workflows work for you?

What tools do you recommend for testing etc?

Are there any tools I can use on both Rails and .Net?

Are there any concentration tips you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

One of the tools that I use heavily in .NET is ReSharper. It costs a nice chunk of change but it enables me to easily and quickly change my code as it provides a quick and simple way to execute tests and refactor code. On top of that it also provides visual hints when I could be doing something better.

As far as portable between Rails and ASP.NET MVC, I have not seen anything. The closest you might get as far as tooling goes is using ReSharper on .NET and then RubyMine in Ruby as they are both written by JetBrains.

For testing in .NET you may want to check out mSpec as it is a BDD framework for .NET and then combine that with using some stuff from MvcContrib for automated UI testing and you might get a closer workflow to what you get out of box with Rails 3.

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert and am continuing to refine my process. I recently blogged about it which should get you off to a great start: http://ntcoding.blogspot.com/2011/01/total-bdd-in-aspnet-mvc_16.html

Hope you like it. BDD helps you stay organised and make sure you are developing the right product.

Spend a lot of time learning gherkin too.

You can use IronRuby in .NET which means RSpec and lots of stuff the rails boys use.

Ciao for now :PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP